# ifup fails when ran in systemd service, debian 10 (raspian)

Tags: bash, systemd, wifi, raspberry-pi

I have a little script named wificheck:

```
ifdown --force $1
sleep 4
ifup $1
```

Set it up in a systemd. If I run it as `sudo ./script.sh wlan0` works fine, but if I run the process `sudo systemctl start wificheck.service`, the wifi interface fails to go up again, with the error in the journalctl log:

```
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local systemd[1]: Started Wifi Check.
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local systemd[1]: wificheck.service: Succeeded.
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local wpa_supplicant[3244]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local wpa_supplicant[3244]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local wpa_supplicant[3244]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=50:c7:bf:f9:12:d9 
Dec 25 19:51:55 kraken.local wpa_supplicant[3244]: ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
```

The service is:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Wifi Check

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/pi/scripts/wificheck wlan0
```

Do not know what to check next. Tips? Thanks!

Comment: You're using a pre/non-systemd networking tool from within systemd. That is probably the main problem.

Comment: Hm where exactly does that unit file live?

Comment: @MarcusMüller /etc/systemd/system